# Set multiple rows slices to value, with a unique slice for each row

Tags: arrays, numpy

Given a 2d array, I can set a row slice to a particular value

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(25).reshape(5,-1).astype(int)
a[0][2:4] = 1.0
a
```

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I am trying to set multiple row slices to a particular value, with a unique slice for each row.

I have the start and end indices for the slices in two arrays

```
starts = np.array([2, 0, 1, 3, 2])
ends = np.array([5, 3, 4, 5, 4])
```

But I can't seem to figure out a way to set these slices for the 2d array to a particular value

```
a[starts:ends] = 1
```

Results in `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Comment: If the slice langths are all the same, use `linspace` to make a 2d array of the columns, and use advanced indexing.

Comment: In my case, slice lengths are not the same. What do you think of the solution I submitted? I concatenated the starts and ends to the zeros array, then used np. apply_along_axis to set the slices row by row, and sliced out the additional columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the last dimension of the target array is big, then using a basic Python loop is relatively efficient because the overhead of the python loop will be small compared to filling the array. Otherwise, AFAIK Numpy does not provide any way to do this operation efficiently (mainly because of the variable-size of the slices). Here is a basic code with Python loops:

```py
for i, start, end in zip(range(starts.size), starts.tolist(), ends.tolist()):
    a[i, start:end] = 1
```

If you want a faster code then you can use Numba so to make the loop faster. Note that you do not need to call `tolist` in that case (its purpose is to make the code faster by not working with Numpy integer types but CPython integers).

Comment: What do you think of the solution I submitted? I concatenated the starts and ends to the zeros array, then used np. apply_along_axis to set the slices row by row, and sliced out the additional columns

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has a function that allows you apply operations to arrays, along a particular axis individually, using a function. So in my case, I can apply the operation uniquely to each row.

apply_along_axis doesn't allow arguments to be passed to the function except for the array itself, so I first concatenate the start and end indices to my zeros array, and then slice them out of the result.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(25).reshape(5,-1).astype(int)

starts = np.array([2, 0, 1, 3, 2])
ends = np.array([5, 3, 4, 5, 4])

startsT = np.expand_dims(starts, axis=0).transpose()
endsT = np.expand_dims(ends, axis=0).transpose()

aa = np.concatenate((a, startsT, endsT), axis=1)

def set_1s_by_slice(x):
    x[x[-2]:x[-1]] = 1
    return x

pen = np.apply_along_axis(set_1s_by_slice, 1, aa)
ult = pen[:,0:5]
ult
```

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

From looking at the source code, this may not be faster that iterating through the rows

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.22.0/numpy/lib/shape_base.py#L267-L414

It seems that there are conversions to lists, though I am not certain.

Comment: One can see that `apply_along_axis` actually iterates over the values using a basic for loop so it will not be faster. Moreover, the use of `concatenate` is quite inefficient (both in term of memory and speed). On big array this should be much slower and this makes the code more complex too. While `tolist` may add a significant overhead, `apply_along_axis` should have a much bigger overhead.

Answer (score 0):

This seems even more computationally efficient than the other answer which uses `apply_along_axis`

```
indices = np.arange(a.shape[1])
mask = (indices >= starts[:, np.newaxis]) & (indices < ends[:, np.newaxis])
a[mask] = 1
```